# Driver/Code signing

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, driver

To be honest, I myself have no idea where to put this, but I'm putting this in here since the signing process requires VS's signtool. I am a bit confused here regarding signing and digital certificate.

Correct me if I am wrong.

1) There is two types of signing : code signing and driver signing. Driver must do the latter, while end-user software only needs to do the code signing.

2) Driver signing requires a digital certificate from sources like VeriSign, GlobalSign. While for code signing, we can generate our own certificate using our own generated public key.

Did I understand things correctly?

Answer (score 2):

> There is two types of signing : code signing and driver signing.
>   Driver must do the latter, while end-user software only needs to do
>   the code signing.

The 2 types are: code signing and EV code signing. Drivers require the later plus additional verification and approval, but only when it comes for drivers for Windows 10.

> Driver signing requires a digital certificate from sources like
>   VeriSign, GlobalSign. While for code signing, we can generate our own
>   certificate using our own generated public key.

EV signing (used for drivers) comes from the same companies however they have a hardware token included which is require for each signing,

Drivers for Windows 10 require the following:

1. An [EV (Extended Validation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate) code signing which [requires a hardware token](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1271890/EV-Code-Signing-with-a-hardware-token) and costs more than a regular code signing certificate.
2. [Submission to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/hardware-certification-submissions) to be counter code signed by them. To do so, the signer (who must [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/register-for-the-hardware-program) with Microsoft hardware program).
   This requirement is since January 2016.

There is an excellent [tutorial](https://manualzz.com/doc/30290742/etoken-software-developer-s-guide) about the process.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I learned driver signing using Kernel-Mode Code Signing Walkthrough  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487328.aspx (available for download as doc file). I have never heard about code signing of kernel-mode drivers. For drivers, there are two signing types: test-sign and release-sign. Test-sign is used for development process, Win7 and Vista 64 bit allow test-signed drivers only in special mode. Release-sign is used for production release and  requires purchasing digital certificate. Release-signed driver can be installed in any Windows version without restrictions.

Kernel-Mode Code Signing Walkthrough contains step-by-step instructions for test and release-signing of kernel-mode drivers.

Comment: Hmm.. how about this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing

It never mentions anything about kernel-mode drivers. I thought the code signing is used when and for desktop applications?

Comment: In my answer I am talking only about driver signing. 64-bit Windows (starting from Vista) don't allow unsigned drivers. I don't know about other software products signing, though, as user, I see that many downloaded programs (like ActiveX controls, for example) are signed.

Comment: The problem I'm facing here is the people in my company is using FTDI driver, which is already signed by Microsoft. We edited the template .inf file to cater for our hardware, and someone says that we need to sign the install file. (it becomes a problem because he's now gone from the company, and no one else knows about signing process)

Do I need to do driver signing on the install file? Or just code signing? This is my main concern..

Comment: @user1491884 You do need to sign .inf file. Driver signing procedure creates a single signature for both .sys (binary) and .inf files. Then during driver installation the signature verification fails if any of the files were changed.

Comment: I see. I guess I need to do code signing on the .inf file? (Actually I am less clear on all the terms used... sorry!)

How do I sign the .inf file? Do I need digital cert from CA? Or I can generate my key and just sign it into that .inf file? Keep in mind that the driver is to be used by our end user.

Comment: @user1491884 Here is the link on driver signing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544865(v=vs.85).aspx 
For end users you do need to get a cert from CA. But you may start with test signing to get familiar with the process.